# Openiddict - option.UseOpenIddict not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openiddict

I am trying to implement Openidict on my ongoing project but i got some problem on there. 
After adding all required package following error occured. How do i solve the issue. Any idea??
[image]

There are tha packages installed on my project

[image]

Comment: Did you add a reference to the `OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore` NuGet package?

Comment: @KévinChalet Yes i have already added

Comment: Try referencing the latest version `2.0.1` instead of using wildcards. If it still doesn't work, consider posting a repro on GitHub and I'll take a look.

Comment: @KévinChalet Thank you. It is working now

Comment: Glad it worked! :)